# Getting garbage when using operator ...

Tags: c++, operators, variadic-functions

I'm trying to use operator "..." but getting troubles:

```
void Func(int diff, CTester* pcTester, int params ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, params);
    for(int i = 0; i < params; i++) {
        int val = va_arg(ap, int);
        cout << "[" << i << "] = " << val << "\n";
        if (diff > val) {
            // some logic
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

I'm calling Func in this way:

```
Func(1359, pcTester, 10, 20, 30, 40);
```

I expect to see in console the prints of [0]=10 [1]=20 [2]=30 [3]=40
But I'm getting too many prints:

```
[0] = 20
[1] = 30
[2] = 40
[3] = 4197568
[4] = 26221600
[5] = 0
[6] = 4196640
[7] = 4197568
[8] = 1152895024
[9] = 0
```

As you can see I have 10 prints (instead of 4) and the first value (10) is  not in the list

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You do `for int i = 0; i < params; i++`, and you passed `10` as the argument for `params`. So you should expect 10 loops (although actually it is undefined behaviour since you didn't pass 10 more arguments). Try calling as `Func(1359, pcTester, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40);`

Comment: The `...` in your code is not an operator (an operator operates on other expressions to produce another expression, e.g. `+` can operate on `2` and `3` to give `5`).  The `...` is actually part of syntax for a function parameter list that indicates there will be un-prototyped arguments to follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior.

You are treating the argument `params` to be number of arguments following it but you are not passing enough arguments.

```
Func(1359, pcTester, 10, 20, 30, 40); // There are only 3 arguments after 10.
```

You need to make sure that they match. Use:

```
// 3 arguments after params
Func(1359, pcTester, 3, 20, 30, 40);
```

or

```
// 4 arguments after params
Func(1359, pcTester, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40);
```

or

```
// 10 arguments after params
Func(1359, pcTester, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110);
```

Comment: you didnt answer his question. in your example he want see the first value (10)

Answer (score 1):

Better use C++ variadic templates and a `std::initializer_list` to fix the type to `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class CTester {};

template < typename ... Args >
void Func(int diff, CTester* pcTester, Args ... params)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(int val : std::initializer_list<int>{ params ... })
  {
    std::cout << "[" << i << "] = " << val << "\n";
    if (diff > val) {
      // some logic
    }
    ++i;
  }
}

int main()
{
  CTester * pcTester = new CTester;
  Func(1359, pcTester, 10, 20, 30, 40);
  delete pcTester;
}
```

[Demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/RleNmf)